# Delete a comment from Asana API

Tags: asana

Is there a way to delete a comment from the API? The UI allows it but could not find anything in API documentation. Tried sending a DELETE to /stories/story-id but got a forbidden response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting stories via the API is not supported at this time. Sorry, I usually try to have something more encouraging to say, but I'm not really sure when we'll get to this - it may not even be something we want to support (people rely somewhat on the stories as a kind of audit log, and while it's one thing to allow people to manually undo a comment, it's another to open up the API to allow, say, bulk removing of comments).

Comment: Alright, just felt like there should be some kind of symmetry between the operations available in the UI and the API. Thanks

Comment: Most of the time, yes, that's what we aim for. And I'm not saying it can't happen, just that I'm not 100% sure that it's just an oversight and not an intentional omission.

Comment: By the same rationale you would not allow task deletes from the API, but you do (and it should stay that way). So oversight?

Comment: You can always get deleted tasks out of the trash - deleted comments I don't think we have a way to restore.

Comment: It seems the same is true of attachments. There doesn't appear to be an API to delete attachments (or attachments as stories). :(